R Script to forecast volatility of monthly crude oil prices using GARCH
This is my first time writing a script for volatility forecasting and I am fairly new to econometrics. I chose to analyze monthly WTI crude oil prices of past 20 years and determine volatility as well as do forecasting. I tried to choose fairly simple models (AR1) and GARCH's of (1,0) and (1,1).
This is my code:
library(rugarch)
library(lmtest)
library(forecast)
library(fGarch)
library(urca)

data<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\eldod\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\rcode\\MCOILWTICO.csv")
tail(data)

ts_data<-ts(data[,2], start = c(2004,1), end = c(2024,1), frequency = 12)
plot(ts_data)
grid()
acf(ts_data)

summary(ur.df(ts_data, type = "drift", selectlags = "AIC"))

dl_data<-diff(log(ts_data))

summary(ur.df(dl_data, type = "drift", selectlags = "AIC"))

plot(dl_data, ylab="", xlab="")
grid()

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
acf(dl_data)
pacf(dl_data)

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
ar1<-arima(dl_data, c(1,0,0))
ar1
summary(ar1)
res1 <- residuals(ar1)
pacf(res1)
coeftest(ar1)

ar2<-arima(dl_data, c(2,0,0))
ar2
summary(ar1)
res2 <- residuals(ar2)
pacf(res2)
coeftest(ar2)

ma1<-arima(dl_data, c(0,0,1))
ma1
summary(ma1)
res3 <- residuals(ma1)
pacf(res3)
coeftest(ma1)

ar1$aic
ar2$aic
ma1$aic

forecast <- forecast(ar1, h=12)
plot(forecast)
grid()
forecast
    
checkresiduals(ar1)

# GARCH(1,0)
spec.garch10 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",
                                                 garchOrder = c(1,0)),
                           mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,0)))
garchModel10 <- ugarchfit(spec.garch10, data=dl_data)
garchModel10

vol_garch10 <- ts(garchModel10@fit$sigma^2,end = c(2024,1), frequency = 12)
plot(vol_garch10, xlab="", ylab="")
grid()

# GARCH(1,1)
spec.garch11 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",
                                                 garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                           mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,0)))
garchModel11 <- ugarchfit(spec.garch11, data=dl_data)
garchModel11

vol_garch11 <- ts(garchModel11@fit$sigma^2,end = c(2024,1), frequency = 12)
plot(vol_garch11, xlab="", ylab="")

# EGARCH(1,1)
spec.egarch11 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH",
                                                  garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                            mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,0)))
eGarchModel11 <- ugarchfit(spec.egarch11, data=dl_data)
eGarchModel11

vol_egarch11 <- ts(eGarchModel11@fit$sigma^2,end = c(2024,1), frequency = 12)
plot(vol_egarch11, xlab="", ylab="")

# TGARCH(1,0)
spec.tgarch10 <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH",
                        submodel = "TGARCH",
                        garchOrder = c(1,0)
  ),
  mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,0))
)

tGarchModel10 <- ugarchfit(spec.tgarch10, data=dl_data)
tGarchModel10

vol_tgarch10 <- ts(tGarchModel10@fit$sigma^2,end = c(2024,1), frequency = 12)
plot(vol_tgarch10, xlab="", ylab="")

# TGARCH(1,1)
spec.tgarch11 <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH",
                        submodel = "TGARCH",
                        garchOrder = c(1,1)
  ),
  mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,0))
)

tGarchModel11 <- ugarchfit(spec.tgarch11, data=dl_data)
tGarchModel11

vol_tgarch11 <- ts(tGarchModel11@fit$sigma^2,end = c(2024,1), frequency = 12)
plot(vol_tgarch11, xlab="", ylab="")

acf(residuals(tGarchModel11, standardize = TRUE))
acf(residuals(tGarchModel11, standardize = TRUE)^2)

forec <- ugarchforecast(tGarchModel11, data = dl_data, n.ahead = 12)
forec
plot(forec, which=1)

This is my ARIMA forecast result:

This is my GARCH Forecast (forec) result:

I have several main questions from the results:

Should my forecast results be done with diff(log(ts_data)), over
the WEB I have seen forecasts on actual time series (or only
log()'s of them).
How do you interpret such forecast results?
TBU

Data source: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DCOILWTICO#0

Unfortunately the Cross Validated has canceled my question.

Shadowing
It's bad practice to shadow built-ins:

forecast <- forecast(ar1, h = 12)


You should choose another name to store the forecast output, e.g.:
fc <- forecast(ar1, h = 12)


Transforming
Currently you log-transform when fitting but don't back-transform when forecasting:

dl_data <- diff(log(ts_data))
#               ^^^ log-transformed
ar1 <- arima(dl_data, c(1, 0, 0))
fc <- forecast(ar1, h = 12)
#              ^^^ needs to be back-transformed


You were questioning whether it's necessary to log-transform, but that's a separate issue. Since your current code does log-transform, it needs to be undone when forecasting. The author of the forecast package recommends automatic back-transformation by using Arima (capital A) with lambda = 0:
ar1 <- Arima(dl_data, c(1, 0, 0), lambda = 0)
#      ^                          ^^^^^^^^^^
fc <- forecast(ar1, h = 12)


Tuning

Should my forecast results be done with diff(log(ts_data))? Over the web I have seen forecasts on actual time series (or only log()'s of them).

These questions are better suited for Cross Validated and probably out of scope for Code Review. It's also not my expertise, so in cases like this, I'd just use auto.arima to automatically determine the model parameters (including the differencing order):

Returns best ARIMA model according to either AIC, AICc or BIC value. The function conducts a search over possible model within the order constraints provided.

Putting it all together:
ar <- auto.arima(
    log(ts_data),           # let auto.arima handle differencing, so don't diff manually
    lambda = 0,             # let auto.arima handle back-transforming
    stepwise = FALSE,       # recommended unless too slow
    approximation = FALSE,  # recommended unless too slow
)
fc <- forecast(ar, h = 12)  # don't shadow built-ins

